# How can I change the dimension of an array?

Tags: python

How to change this array into a 5*2 matrix?

This is my array:

```
[[ ([[315, 327, 333, 334, 339]], [[146, 143, 145, 145, 146]])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy provides reshape method to reshape an array into array of any dimension with the same number of elements. You can use the method to reshape array of any shape into another shape as long as the product of the original array dimension(s) is/are equal to the product of new array dimension(s).

```
import numpy as np

a=[[ ([[315, 327, 333, 334, 339]], [[146, 143, 145, 145, 146]])]]
b=np.array(a).reshape((5,2))
list_b=b.tolist();
print list_b
# [[315, 327], [333, 334], [339, 146], [143, 145], [145, 146]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to change the array into a 5*2 matrix

I'm really not sure what you meant by that, but if you want to rotate it (2*5 --> 5*2) you can try this

```
arrays = [[315, 327, 333, 334, 339], [146, 143, 145, 145, 146]]
newArrays = [[] for _ in range(len(arrays[0]))] # initialise this list first
for arr in arrays:
    for i,item in enumerate(arr):
        newArrays[i].append(item) 
print(newArrays)
# [[315, 146], [327, 143], [333, 145], [334, 145], [339, 146]]
```